# Android exception permission denied even after granting permission?

Tags: java, android

What am I doing wrong?
I have tried googlign the problem, but people mostly say it is an issue with android Q, but I don't think my problem is that.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest ...>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

Java:

```
void takePhoto(){

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA},2);

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)
    {
            File photoFile = createPhotoFile();
            if(photoFile != null){
                pathToFile = photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                Uri photoURI = getUriForFile(this, this.getPackageName() + ".fileprovider", photoFile);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
            }
        }

}

private File createPhotoFile() {
    String name = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File storageDir = getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = null;
    try{
        image = File.createTempFile(name, ".jpg", storageDir);
    } catch(IOException e){
        Log.d("myLog", "Except: " + e.toString());
    }
    return image;
}
```

Comment: Did your user actually grant permissions to your application?

Comment: `requestPermissions()` is asynchronous. When it returns, you do not yet have the permission. You are going in and attempting to use external storage before the user has a chance to grant the permission. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#perm-request).

Comment: What happens if the method gets called again? Shouldn't it have permission then? Because it doesn't have it even on second call. Also, I did give permission as user